# How do I stop a second instance of my application from executing if one is already running in JAVA?

Tags: java, javaw

When I run my application using the .jar file, the GUI is displayed and javaw.exe shows up in System Processes in the task manager. But when I run the .jar file again without closing the first one, a second javaw.exe process starts and a second GUI is displayed. How do I stop this? I want there to be only one instance of my application at a time no matter how many times I run the .jar file.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of solutions [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0288.html).

Note, though, that the socket solution needs to be modified if you are worried that something else on the same machine could be using the same port.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to open a socket on a fixed port number. The OS will enforce that only one process may do this.

Answer (score -1):

Register a value in a file, is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: In case of crash of the program, how will you again start the application?